# Why does this for loop log "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

So I have this javascript object, and I want to loop through and print out each of it's property values.

Here's the code:

```
var names = {
            "firstName":"Billy",
            "lastName":"John",
            "age":30
        };

for(var a in names){
    console.log(names.a);
}
```

And it console.logs "undefined" 3 times.

But if I do something like this:

```
for(var a in names){
    console.log(names[a]);
}
```

It prints out Billy, John, 30.

If I console.log `names.firstName` outside the loop it works. And considering that during the first loop execution `a` is `firstName`, it should work.

Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Because of how property names work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because using dot notation (`names.a`) you are accessing the property `a` on your object, this property is of cause undefined.

When you use bracket notation `names[a]` then the variable will be evaluated and the statement will look like this: `names['firstName']`, `names['lastName']`, ...

Normally you would always use dot notations when accessing properties, but in your case - because you need to access the property with the name the variable holds - you will need to use bracket notation.

Another scenario you would use bracket notation is when you will need to access a property that have a name that cannot be written using dot notation. Consider this:

```
var a = { "my-special property": 1 };
// Try to access it via dot notation:'
console.log(a.my-special property); // SyntaxError
// But with bracket notation:
console.log(a['my-special property']); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `names` does not have a `.a` property.  `a` refers to a variable whose value is the property.

Answer (score 2):

`names[a]` and `names.a` are not equivalent.

`a` is a variable that references a string.

`names.a` expects a key named `a` in your names object.

`names[a]` equates to each of `names.firstName`, `name.lastName` and `names.age`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote:

```
var names = {
            "a":"property a",
            "firstName":"Billy",
            "lastName":"John",
            "age":30
        };
```

Then the loop:

```
for(var a in names){
    console.log(names.a);
}
```

would log `property a` three times, understand?